# Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Tags: java, error-handling, netbeans, computer-science, csc

I am currently using the newest version of Apache Netbeans to do an assignment for class. Whenever I try to run my code I get this error:
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project VitaminStore: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated as I am so confused on what to do. <3

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We need to be able to reproduce your problem to help you. Please [edit] your question and create a [mcve].

Comment: ?delete and re-install the program?

Comment: Can you please add your code and maven pom.xml as well. org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4. I have a gut feeling that this is a maven project based on error above. My assumption is that you are trying to use an existing project and trying to run it. If you don't have maven then try running with mvnw instead of mvn